# How can i get kryo log in Akka project

Tags: java, akka, kryo

I have an Akka-cluster project developed in Java. Where I used kryo serialization. How can I get the log of kryo serialization ? I want to know all non mapping classes because here idstrategy = "explict". Currently if I missed to add a class in the mapping section the whole code is working without any errors, but my worker actors do not receive this class objects. It effect in my final output. So anyone help me to implement kryo logging in my project ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [akka-kryo-serialization](https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization), there are two settings that control kryo logging behavior:

```
  # Log implicitly registered classes. Useful, if you want to know all
  # classes which are serialized. You can then use this information in
  # the mappings and/or classes sections
  implicit-registration-logging = false

  # If enabled, Kryo logs a lot of information about serialization process.
  # Useful for debugging and low-level tweaking
  kryo-trace = false
```

You might not be able to use the former one (`implicit-registration-logging`) right away, as you have a restrictive id strategy (and I'm not sure what kryo will do in this case), but the second one is probably exactly what you want